# Multiple "could not be resolved" problems using Eclipse with minGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, c++11, mingw32

I have recently installed (the latest builds of) 'Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers' and minGW (4.8.1) to help me to get back into C++ after a long time away.

I have added `-std=c++11` to `Other flags` at `C/C++ Build/Settings/Tool Settings/GCC C++ Compiler/Miscellaneous`

I have a small program utilizing a number of C++11 features (e.g. using the `chrono` library, `.emplace_back`).

After Run I get multiple unresolved issues in the Problems window, as Pasted below).

Interestingly, the program does compile and run ok.

1. With this, is there something I'm not setting up in Eclipse to resolve these issues?
2. Does anyone know if there still an issue with the `to_string()` function in minGW (4.8.1) e.g. the following does not compile:

   ```
   window.setTitle("Bullets on screen: " + to_string(bullets.size()) + " currentSlice: " + to_string(currentSlice) + " FT: " + to_string(ft) + " FPS: " + to_string(fps) );
   ```

   It does compile using Visual Studio Express 2013 (though it has an issue with the accuracy of the `chrono` library, hence the switch to minGW).

   Thanks.

Eclipse 'Problem' window output:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
 Symbol 'duration' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 19 Semantic Error
 Function 'now' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 143 Semantic Error
 Function 'duration_cast' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 160 Semantic Error
 Function 'now' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 158 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'chrono' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 8 Semantic Error
 Type 'std::centi' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 20 Semantic Error
 Type 'std::chrono::seconds' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 24 Semantic Error
 Type 'std::time_t' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 48 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 47 Semantic Error
 Function 'now' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 44 Semantic Error
 Function 'now' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 39 Semantic Error
 Type 'std::chrono::system_clock' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 38 Semantic Error
 Function 'end' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 214 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'time_point' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 38 Semantic Error
 Function 'end' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 212 Semantic Error
 Type 'milli' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 161 Semantic Error
 Method 'count' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 161 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration_cast' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 160 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 161 Semantic Error
 Method 'count' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 51 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration_cast' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 30 Semantic Error
 Method 'count' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 30 Semantic Error
 Function 'to_time_t' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 48 Semantic Error
 Method 'count' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 32 Semantic Error
 Function 'ctime' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 50 Semantic Error
 Method 'count' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 33 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 22 Semantic Error
 Invalid arguments '
 Candidates are:
 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bullet *,std::vector<Bullet,std::allocator<Bullet>>> erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bullet *,std::vector<Bullet,std::allocator<Bullet>>>)
 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bullet *,std::vector<Bullet,std::allocator<Bullet>>> erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bullet *,std::vector<Bullet,std::allocator<Bullet>>>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bullet *,std::vector<Bullet,std::allocator<Bullet>>>)
 ' Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 212 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'ratio' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 22 Semantic Error
 Invalid arguments '
 Candidates are:
 #0 remove_if(#0, #0, #1)
 ' Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 212 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration_cast' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 28 Semantic Error
 Method 'count' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 28 Semantic Error
 Method 'emplace_back' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 191 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'ratio' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 19 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 20 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'duration' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 21 Semantic Error
 Function 'begin' could not be resolved Test2.cpp /Test2/src line 212 Semantic Error
 Symbol 'ratio' could not be resolved chronotest.cpp /chronotest/src line 21 Semantic Error
```

---

[Edit]: Apologies for not including error details for the remaining "to_string". The Eclipse 'Problem' window output has the following:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'to_string' was not declared in this scope  Test2.cpp   /Test2/src  line 170    C/C++ Problem
Function 'to_string' could not be resolved  Test2.cpp   /Test2/src  line 170    Semantic Error
Function 'to_string' could not be resolved  Test2.cpp   /Test2/src  line 170    Semantic Error
unused variable 'currentSlice' [-Wunused-variable]  Test2.cpp   /Test2/src  line 125    C/C++ Problem
Function 'to_string' could not be resolved  Test2.cpp   /Test2/src  line 170    Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void setTitle(const sf::String &)
'   Test2.cpp   /Test2/src  line 170    Semantic Error
Function 'to_string' could not be resolved  Test2.cpp   /Test2/src  line 170    Semantic Error
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814536/eclipse-c-symbol-std-could-not-be-resolved

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc. -> Providers -> CDT GCC built-in compiler settings`, deactivate `Use global provider shared between projects` and add the command line argument `-std=c++11`.

The eclipse live code analysis does not share the same settings with the build compiler. You can also change the setting globally (not just for the project) in `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`.

Edit: You need to `#include <string>` to use `std::to_string`.

Comment: Many thanks for this - most parser issues involving references have now been resolved. The "to_string" issue remains. Apologies for not including error details here. I've edited my original question to include these errors.

Comment: @Jim I added to my answer.

Comment: After much Googling I've found out that in order to get the "to_string" function to work in minGW you (currently) have to download using the minGW w64 fork (after reading links such as  http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015 then using the links in http://www.rioki.org/2013/10/16/mingw-w64.html). Hope this helps others.

Comment: It is also important to note that this works for "Linux GCC" toolchain. I have foolishly attempted to try with "Cross GCC", which failed miserably.

Comment: I had the first part, but still had `array` not recognised even if the code was executed correctly !!! So the second part of your answer solved it: http://i.imgur.com/EFrOeBP.png (Rebuild the index too after!!!)

Comment: While I could see that the live code analysis obviously didn't use the same process as the build compiler (because it compiles clean, but the editor shows me lots of errors) never in a million years would I have found that switch. You're a genius. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I'm adding  a few details to the answers given by @Nabla and @Enissey.

When adding the command line argument, for example, CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cygwin in Global preferences,

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

do it like so,

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 "${INPUTS}"
```

To [rebuild the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008293/clean-eclipse-index-it-is-out-of-sync-with-code#3008319), right-click on your project, go under the Index sub-menu, and choose "Rebuild."

In my case, I made the changes globally and rebuilt the index.

Answer (score 0):

Re download the `gcc` compiler from:

```
http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran
```

install it in `c:\minGW` folder use new worksapce / fresh eclipse setting , it work like a charm!

Don't forget to restart before trying , re build and set etc.

as well to set `MinGW` as a default tool chain windows -> preferences -> New C++.. ->set `MinMG` as a tool chain preferred.

If you cannot see it on the list , deselect the "show project types...."  as well when creating the project.