# c++ linux eclipse function runtime_error could not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, c++11, runtime-error, throw

in centos eclipse.  Got a bug says "function runtime_error could not be resolved".  I added -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x in the settings and rebuild the index.  (see [Multiple "could not be resolved" problems using Eclipse with minGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065616/multiple-could-not-be-resolved-problems-using-eclipse-with-mingw) )
it still shows a bug in the CDT.
But in my makefile I added -std=c++0x it got compiled with no error.

the line has the bug is
throw runtime_error("error msg");
I included those header files

```
    #include <cerrno>
    #include <system_error>
    using namespace std;
    void main()
    {
         throw runtime_error("blabla");
    }
```

Comment: in the code I also used  using namespace std; or you can add std::runtime_error("....");

Comment: in the code you can add std:: it hints the selections has "__throw_runtime_error()", when I use it, it has compile error "error: invalid use of ‘void’"

Comment: the code change to   __throw_runtime_error(" "); from throw runtime_error("  ");  it compiled.