# Eclipse shows type error but can resolve just fine using 'Open Declaration'

Tags: c, eclipse

this is an issue I had multiple times but mostly i just ignored it.
I'm working on an embedded project using eclipse & some supplier libraries in C. Project compiles fine & runs, but it show errors on lines like

```
foo = DEFINE_FROM_OTHER_FILE;
```

Error by error decorator:

```
Type 'DEFINE_FROM_OTHER_FILE' could not be resolved.
```

I raised every indexer setting to the max, but it still shows annoying errors.
The file in front of me is <700 lines, i get the same problem on files of different sizes.
Project is around 15k lines including supplied code, so not that big?

Thanks for this community :)

Comment: Could be the same problem like [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051550/eclipse-cdt-error-symbol-xxx-could-not-be-resolved)  or [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065616/multiple-could-not-be-resolved-problems-using-eclipse-with-mingw)?

Comment: Tried both, nothing gained. Should maybe add that I'm using CodeBench 2014.05-46, but I had the problem in the past using Eclipse & OpenARM Toolchain (CB = Work, OpenARM = Hobby)